# Why std::nounitbuf doesn't do anything on MSVC?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, cout, flush

I am writing a course on modern C++ and wanting to explain how the flush operations work, so I decided to disable the automatic flush in order to write to the buffer only when `std::cout` is destroyed.

For that, only one standard function exists and it is the manipulator `std::nounitbuf`.

However, this doesn't work on **MSVC**.

What surprises me the most is that the alternative in C, the `setvbuf` function, actually allows you to deactivate the automatic flush.
It bothers me a little because I want to teach C++ and not C.

Can anyone help me? thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::nounitbuf; // doesn't work (output is two Hello World before the 5 seconds delay)
    //setvbuf(stdout, nullptr, _IOFBF, BUFSIZ); // work (output is one Hello World, then another one after the 5 seconds)

    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hello World";

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{ 5 });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how it does not work?  You should at least get one line of output before the program ends as `std::endl` calls `flush` to flush out the line that was just sent to the stream.

Comment: since you explicitly flush the buffers with `std::endl` then `std::nounitbuf` do not have chance to do its job. Also `std::nounitbuf` is default setting.

Comment: You don't understand, even without explicit flushing, it doesn't work! That's the point. You can try it if you want: std::nounitbuf is not working (btw std::unitbuf seems to work well)

Comment: `std::cout` is not unit buffered, so setting `nounitbuf` doesn't do anything. Try it with `std::cerr`. And note that unit buffering means flushing after each insertion; disabling it doesn't affect `std::endl`, which flushes the stream, nor does it affect line buffering, which flushes when you insert `'\n'`.

Comment: So can you explain to me why setvbuf is working on stdout? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl

> In many implementations, standard output is line-buffered, and writing
> `'\n'` causes a flush anyway, unless `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false)`
> was executed.

Try to remove `std::endl` and `'\n'` from the output and you will get the desired behavior. And as Marek said, `std::nounitbuf` is default setting for `std::cout`.

Comment: Not working too, you can try on your compiler and show the result you will see that the C version is working and the C++ one not (on cout)

Comment: My compiler is gcc 9.3.0. If I remove '\n' and std::endl from your code I have got output after 5 seconds.

Comment: Are you sure `\n` causes a flush?

Comment: @MaxKozlov in MSVC there's no line buffering so `\n` won't flush the stream: [*`_IOLBF`: For some systems, this provides line buffering. However, for Win32, the behavior is the same as `_IOFBF` - Full Buffering.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setvbuf?view=msvc-160)

Answer (score 0):

> Why std::nounitbuf doesn't do anything?

Most probably because `unitbuf` flag is **not set** by default for standard `cout` stream. ([Standard narrow.stream.objects](https://eel.is/c++draft/narrow.stream.objects) requires it should be set only for `cerr`).

> Can anyone help me?

C++ are synchronized (not buffered) with stdio streams. What you write `std::cout << "something"` goes *straight* to `FILE*` `stdout`. As it goes straight there, `stdout` buffering is all that matters.

Disable synchronization with stdio streams and try then. Read about [std::ios::sync_with_stdio](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio). The following works for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
int main() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);

    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{ 5 });
}
```

Comment: Still not working (see other answers) at least on msvc and clang

Comment: :/ so maybe it is set. Try also unsetting it. [Seems to work here](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/CourteousShadySolidstatedrive#main.cpp).

Comment: trust me I've tried everything I can x) (but the std::unitbuf is working, but that's not what I need)

Comment: From my test on msvc it works only when `setvbuf` is used AND when `nounitbuf` is applied on `cout` (note this is default flag for `std::cout` so `unitbuf` must be applied to disable it).